# Get Content from URL containing special characters (< and >)

Tags: php, file, web

I have a URL like

```
$url = 'https://website.com/?param=1&test3=<TEST>answer</TEST>';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
```

When trying to access the format below with file_get_contents it does not work since it contains the < and > characters, but they are needed as the website I need to access uses this method.

Do you have any idea how can I overcome this ?

I tried encoding it but to no avail.

When I try with the same URL but without the test3 parameter it works just fine (but I need the test3 param)

Comment: Show the actual code that you're using

Comment: updated, the params are similar

Comment: You can try using `&lt;` and `&gt;` if no other encoding/decoding worked. But that could throw an error.

Comment: Using my above suggestion did in fact echo `https://website.com/?param=1&test3=<TEST>answer</TEST>` however the source contains `https://website.com/?param=1&test3=&lt;TEST&gt;answer&lt;/TEST&gt;`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I would think urlencode() would be more ideal for this than html entities.

Comment: @Devon I agree. Yet the OP states that encoding was tried. The only thing is, OP didn't state which one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ah, I missed that line.  That is surprising then.

Comment: @Devon It is, but again, we don't know which one was used. It could be anything, and maybe OP thinks that one function is encoding but in fact may not be. Plus, OP is using some type of framework; looks like it.

Comment: @Devon OP hasn't responded to any comments or your answer below. I'm moving on. Espresso's ready ;-) cheers

Answer (score 0):

[urlencode()](https://www.php.net/urlencode) is used to encode variables properly in the query string.

```
$url = 'https://website.com/?param=1&test3='.urlencode('<TEST>answer</TEST>');
$data = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: Let me know if OP chooses this as correct. I will +1 then. I've no way to test this right now.